# fputcsv displaying data in browser instead of downloading data as CSV file

Tags: php, fputcsv

I am using fputcsv function to export data as CSV file but it is displaying all data in browser instead of downloading this as CSV file. Here is my code

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, $column_headings);
fclose($output);
```

Data is displaying correctly in browser but I want to download this as export.csv file.I do not know what is wrong with this. Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control how the browser handles the `text/csv` content type, however, you can tell the browser it should treat the data as binary.

`header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I replace header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'); with header('Content-Type: binary/octet-stream'); but it did not work.

Comment: Try application/octet-stream;

Comment: If it is still displaying, then either something is wrong with your content-type header or browser.  Double check your headers in the developer console and make sure the content type is what you think it is, and if it is opening in a different program other than the browser, this is the intended behavior for your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I added `ob_start();` at the start of my file and now I can export files.